# How to find what pages are internally linking to a page?

Tags: links

I have searched and searched and I must be missing something really obvious. Sorry.

I want to know which pages internally link to a particular page.

So **page-a** has some content (eg **'look at this'**) that directs the browser to page **'...please look at me'**.

When I am in say list of pages or in the actual target page I want to know what pages have internal links to this page.

Comment: There is no such built-in functionality. You have to extract internal links from each post content to find those linking to the target. Also there are some third-party internal link checker plugins and software like Screaming Frog.

Comment: Thx @MaxYudin but I am talking about pages and not posts. I'll have a look at Screaming Frog.

Comment: '[Page](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/post-types/#page-2)' is a default _post_ type.

Comment: Thx again @MaxYudin. I had a look at Screaming Frog but it's overkill for my needs. The functionality that I seek is some code (plugin) that will read pages in the DB and produce a cross-reference for internal links. A simple table that has a few columns. Eg PageName, Link to target, TargetPageName. Then when I look at the TargetPageName column I can readily see what pages and links are inbound. To be honest I'm shocked something as simple as this does not exist. Hm... maybe a Google tool exists and so no one has bothered to create a plugin?

Comment: I think it doesn't exist because it'd be unnecessarily taxing on the DB to run that query constantly as most sites don't necessarily need that.  What functionality are you attempting to gain from this?  Is it for front end use or back end use?